# How to remove a duplicate disk home folder

Tags: home-directory

I installed Ubuntu Studio 15.10 at first days of December of 2015.

Then I had to install MS Windows 7 Ultimate, into another partition, not the same of Ubuntu.

Because something related with the systems, I had to re-installed Ubuntu, into the same original Ubuntu partition, to get a multi system starting point.

Nothing bad, all it's OK now, BUT... I discovered that I have a duplicate main disk folder, here.

If I open the normal "home" folder (where I expected to find all the system main installation), I find two folders, with different names but with the same content on both.

The main difference between both folders is the date which they were created.

Now, when I want to look for something, I have to see into both folders.

I tried to erase (remove) the oldest folder, but the PCManFM files manager doesn't give me any option to do that. It seems to me like this folder is protected by the system.

How can I remove the oldest folder, without to ruin the system itself?

After to apply the recommended `pwd` and `ls -al` commands into the `home` folder, I got this:

```
root@radiocondellcontrol1-MS-7788:/home# pwd
/home
root@radiocondellcontrol1-MS-7788:/home# ls -al
total 16
drwxr-xr-x  4 root                   root                   4096 ene  3 17:50 .
drwxr-xr-x 24 root                   root                   4096 dic 19 14:52 ..
drwxr-xr-x 44 radio_condell_control1 radio_condell_control1 4096 ene  3 16:04 control1
drwxr-xr-x 47 radio_condell_control1 radio_condell_control1 4096 ene  3 13:57 radio_condell_control1
```

How can I remove the old folder? Can I?

Comment: Please open a terminal in this directory and add the output of the following commands as an [edit] to your question: `pwd` and `ls -al`.

Comment: I did it. Now...

Comment: But there you are in one of the home folders. What I wanted to ask for is `pwd` and `ls -al` in the folder where those duplicate folders are in. Btw. the output of `pwd` was missing in your edit.

Comment: OK, OK. Now I downloaded what you are asking for me. Sorry by the mistake.

Comment: Which is the one you want to remove? Also, which of the two is registered as the home folder of `radio_condell_control1` in `/etc/passwd`?

Comment: I want to remove the oldest: "control1". I don't have any "/etc/passwd" folder.

Comment: There is a simple text file called "passwd". In that file only appear things related to "radio_condell_control1" folder.

Comment: `/etc/passwd` is a text file and without it you couldn't even log in on a local account.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33789/discussion-between-the-seppi-and-juan).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to "the_Seppi" for the helping hand.

I could remove the duplicate folder with the command:

**sudo rm -rf "duplicated folder name and path"**

That's all, folks!!!

Greetings & Blessings from Chile!!!!!!!

Juan